# jmeter: not found in Jenkins

Tags: jmeter, jenkins

I'm trying to run performance tests in Jenkins using JMeter. I have the following shell script

`jmeter -n -t JMeterTest.jmx -l Test.jtl`

I am able to run jmeter locally in my project using `jmeter` or by doing `/usr/local/bin/jmeter`. But I don't know how to do it in Jenkins. Can anyone help me? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have JMeter startup script in your PATH - it is expected that Jenkins doesn't find it. Try providing the full path or something like

```
/usr/local/bin/./jmeter
```

By the way, Jenkins [Performance Plugin page](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Performance+Plugin) recommends launching JMeter via [Maven Plugin](http://jmeter.lazerycode.com/) or [Ant task](http://www.programmerplanet.org/projects/jmeter-ant-task/)

See [5 Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](https://blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui) guide for detailed explanation of JMeter unattended execution options.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have JMeter installed on a jenkins slave?  If so, do you have it setup to use jmeter as a symlink.  That's really all you need to do.  What is the exact error you have?  jmeter not found?